# Invalid command 'FcgidMaxProcesses'

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-fcgid

I try to setup mod_fcgid on Centos and got the message:

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 16 of /var/www/wcm/apache/staging/cmf/fcgi.conf:
```

Invalid command 'FcgidMaxProcesses', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Yesterday i have upgraded the Centos, now
httpd.i386                               2.2.3-63.el5.centos.1         installed
mod_fcgid.i386                           2.2-11.el5                    installed

it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the fcgid module isn't being loaded. Do you have the following line in your configuration?

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
```